# Changing image source when Hubtile "resets"

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

So I wanted to make Hubtile's Image Source change when the Image itself is not visible. Can't find the code of any events which are called then. Is there a trigger that I can use to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Was browsing my old questions.
For this I made a custom Visual state manager which checked the Hubtile state every state changed. When the state was as hidden(or whatever the state name is when the image on the hubtile is hidden) it changed the image on it.

Comment: Possible solution provided here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19586279/is-it-possible-to-handle-the-visual-state-changed-event-for-the-windows-phone-to